# How can I create an ignore_bins for a functional coverage cross to exclude any bins where a coverpoint falls within an external array list?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have an unpacked array of an enumerated type that's declared outside a covergroup and is used in several places:

```
client_e read_only_clients[] = {CLIENT1, CLIENT2};
```

And this covergroup:

```
covergroup cg with function sample ( client_e client, dir_e dir );
  client_cp : coverpoint client;
  dir_cp : coverpoint dir;

  client_dir_cr : cross client_cp, dir_cp;
endgroup
```

I want to create an ignore_bins for the cross that will ignore the bins where client_cp falls within read_only_clients, and dir is WRITE.

Currently, I have the elements of read_only_clients listed again in the ignore_bins declaration like so:

```
client_dir_cr : cross client_cp, dir_cp {
  ignore_bins ignore_read_only_clients = binsof(client_cp) intersect {CLIENT1, CLIENT2} &&
                                         binsof(dir_cp) intersect {WRITE};
}
```

I'm not happy with this as I need to copy paste this list several times across multiple covergroups. So I'd like to just use the array. I've tried doing something like this:

```
client_dir_cr : cross client_cp, dir_cp {
  ignore_bins ignore_read_only_clients = binsof(client_cp) intersect {read_only_clients} &&
                                         binsof(dir_cp) intersect {WRITE};
}
```

and this:

```
client_dir_cr : cross client_cp, dir_cp {
  ignore_bins ignore_read_only_clients = client_dir_cr with (client_cp inside {read_only_clients} &&
                                                             dir_cp == WRITE);
}
```

But both gave me compile errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define read_only_clients and other bins in coverpoint and then use it for ignore_bins.

```
 covergroup cg (client_e read_only_clients[])with function sample ( client_e client, dir_e dir );
  client_cp : coverpoint client { 
     bins read_only_bins[] = read_only_clients;
     bins others[] = default; 
  }
  dir_cp : coverpoint dir;

  client_dir_cr : cross client, dir  {
     ignore_bins ignore_read_only_clients = binsof(client_cp.read_only_bins) 
     &&  binsof(dir_cp) intersect {WRITE}; }
endgroup

// pass read_only_clients as variable. 
    cg = new(read_only_clients);
```

Comment: I'd like each of the clients to have their own bin, and I should clarify the read_only_clients[] array is used in several covergroups so I'm looking for a way to re-use it between them all.

Comment: I updated my answer. can you try that ?